# Custom Class Setter Not Updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class, `KeyCombos` that contains a `Modifier Keys` and `Keys` property:

```
private ModifierKeys _modifierKeys;
private Key _key;

public ModifierKeys ModifierKeys
{
    get { return _modifierKeys; }
    set
    {
        if (_modifierKeys == value)
            return;

        _modifierKeys = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ModifierKeys));
    }
}

public Key Key
{
    get { return _key; }
    set
    {
        if (_key == value)
            return;

        _key = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Key));
    }
}

public KeyCombo(ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Key key)
{
    Key = key;
    ModifierKeys = modifierKeys;
}
```

where `RaisePropertyChanged` is used to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

In my `ViewModel`, I have properties that bind to various key combinations, for example:

```
private KeyCombo _firstKeyCombo;
public KeyCombo FirstKeyCombo
{
    get { return _firstKeyCombo; }
    set
    {
        if (_firstKeyCombo == value)
            return;

        _firstKeyCombo = value;
        // Validation method called here
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstKeyCombo));
    }
}
```

And each part of the `KeyCombo` is set in the `ViewModel`, i.e.:

```
FirstKeyCombo = new KeyCombo(ModifierKeys.Alt, Key.T);
```

The ViewModel also defines:

```
public IEnumerable<Key> Keys => _availableKeys;
ObservableCollection<Key> _availableKey; // set to all available keys
public IEnumerable<ModifierKeys> Modifiers => _modifierKeys;
ObservableCollection<ModifierKeys> _modifierKeys;  // set to all modifier keys
```

Then bound in the `View` to `ComboBoxs`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="2">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="Keys" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding FirstKeyCombo.Key, 
                       Mode=TwoWay, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="Modifiers" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding FirstKeyCombo.ModifierKey, 
                       Mode=TwoWay, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This works fine, the appropriate `Key` and `ModifierKeys` display properly.  I need update the `FirstKeyCombo` via the setter when either the `Key` or `ModiferKeys` is changed (validation over **all** of the `KeyCombo` properties in the ViewModel).  Obviously, my attempt to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not successfully do this.  What should I do to ensure that if either property (`ModiferKeys` or `Keys`) is changed via the `Combobox`, `FirstKeyCombo` gets set?

Comment: **First** Did you place a breakpoint in your `Key` and `Modifier` property set in `KeyCombos` class ?  **Second** is your `XAML` correct ? I see you are binding a `ZoomToFitShortcut.ModifierKey`

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez 1) Yes, the `Key` and `Modifier` are correctly set in 'KeyCombo' when I switch either field via the `ComboBox`.  Only the `getter` in my `view model` is called.  2) Updated (poor copying on my part)

Comment: So, if I'm not wrong you want to raise the `FirstKeyCombo` changed when you set the `Keys` or `Modifiers` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez correct

Comment: Ok, if no one answers this correctly in 1 hour I will post an extended answer kinda busy right now ;)

Comment: Great! Thanks, @JuanCarlosRodriguez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel you shoud "listen" to the PropertyChanged of your Properties and set a new KeyCombo.

So after creating your FirstKeyCombo, add the PropertyChangedEventhandler

```
FirstKeyCombo.PropertyChanged += OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
```

which should look like this:

```
private void OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //remove the handler
  FirstKeyCombo.PropertyChanged -= OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
  //create new object because of referential equlity check in WPF
  FirstKeyCombo = new KeyCombo(FirstKeyCombo.ModifierKeys, FirstKeyCombo.Key);
  //add the handler to the new object
  FirstKeyCombo.PropertyChanged += OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
}
```

Just calling

```
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstKeyCombo));
```

in the event handler would not suffice, because there is a check for referential equality, which would have resulted in no new object.

As to the comment, this is how it would be done with Reflection. KeyCombo.Name must be the name of the Property.

```
private void OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  KeyCombo combo = sender as KeyCombo;
  //remove the handler
  combo.PropertyChanged -= OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
  //create new object because of referential equlity check in WPF
  combo = new KeyCombo(combo.ModifierKeys, combo.Key, combo.Name);
  //add the handler to the new object
  combo.PropertyChanged += OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
  //Get the ViewModel-Type
  Type t = ViewModel.GetType();
  //Get the property with the name
  PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(combo.Name);
  //set the value of the property
  pi.SetValue(ViewModel,combo);
}
```

or with a dictionary. Also KeyCombo.Name must be the name of the Property.

```
private void OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  KeyCombo combo = sender as KeyCombo;
  //remove the handler
  combo.PropertyChanged -= OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
  //create new object because of referential equlity check in WPF
  combo = new KeyCombo(combo.ModifierKeys, combo.Key, combo.Name);
  //add the handler to the new object
  combo.PropertyChanged += OnFirstKeyComboPropertyChanged;
  dictionaryWithAllCombos[combo.Name] = combo;
  RaisePropertyChanged(combo.Name);
}
```

in the ViewModel

```
public FirstKeyCombo FirstKeyCombo
{
  get { return dictionary["FirstKeyCombo"]; }
  set 
  { 
    dictionaryWithAllCombos["FirstKeyCombo"] = value; 
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstKeyCombo));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working.  Is there a way to generalize this for all `KeyCombo` properties?  Otherwise, I'd have to hook the event for a lot of `KeyComb` properties...

Comment: If you add the name of your property to the KeyCombo-Type, you might use reflection, to get the right property and set it via that.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show, how you could do that. There are other ways, f.e. you could store the Combos in a Dictionary<String,KeyCombo> and use the name as accessor. Then in the PropertyGetter you get the one with the right name from the dictionary and in the setter you set the one. That way you don't need reflection.

Comment: Which one did you go for?